# Ask for a passcode with Ionic and RxJS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I want to implement an alert dialog which asks the user for a passcode.
If the passcode is equal to a saved password, the dialog should dismiss.
Otherwise, the dialog should present itself again until the user enter the correct passcode.
For this task I'm using Ionic and in particular [ion-alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert).

The following works as expected.

```typescript
askForPasscode() {
  const alertOpts = {
    backdropDismiss: false,
    header: this.transloco.translate('passcodeEnter'),
    message: this.failedAttempts ? this.transloco.translate('passcodeFailedAttempts', { failedAttempts: this.failedAttempts }) : '',
    inputs: [ {
      name: 'passcode',
      placeholder: this.transloco.translate('passcodeEnter'),
      attributes: { maxlength: passcodeLength, type: 'password' },
    } ],
    buttons: [ {
      text: this.transloco.translate('confirm'),
      handler: this.verifyPasscode.bind(this),
    } ],
  };
  return fromPromise(this.alertCtrl.create(alertOpts)).pipe(
    map(alert => fromPromise(alert.present())));
}

verifyPasscode({ passcode }: any ) {
  const digest = SHA1(passcode).toString();
  this.storage.get('passcode').subscribe(stored => {
    const isFailedAttempt = digest !== stored;
    this.failedAttempts = isFailedAttempt ? this.failedAttempts + 1 : 0;
    if (isFailedAttempt)
      this.askForPasscode().subscribe();
  });
}

this.askForPasscode().subscribe();
```

As refinement, I'd like to move the retry portion outside of the `askForPasscode` method, and manage it with the RxJS operators.
So I have refactored the code in the following way.

```typescript
askForPasscode() {
  const alertOpts = {
    backdropDismiss: false,
    header: this.transloco.translate('passcodeEnter'),
    message: this.failedAttempts ? this.transloco.translate('passcodeFailedAttempts', { failedAttempts: this.failedAttempts }) : '',
    inputs: [ {
      name: 'passcode',
      placeholder: this.transloco.translate('passcodeEnter'),
      attributes: { maxlength: PasscodeLength, type: 'password' },
    } ],
    buttons: [ {
      text: this.transloco.translate('confirm'),
      // handler: this.verifyPasscode.bind(this),
    } ],
  };
  return fromPromise(this.alertCtrl.create(alertOpts)).pipe(
    // map(alert => fromPromise(alert.present())));
    switchMap(alert => {
      alert.present();
      return fromPromise(alert.onDidDismiss());
    }));
}

verifyPasscode(passcode: string) {
  const digest = SHA1(passcode).toString();
  // this.storage.get('passcode').subscribe(stored => {
  return this.storage.get('passcode').pipe(map(stored => {
    const isFailedAttempt = digest !== stored;
    this.failedAttempts = isFailedAttempt ? this.failedAttempts + 1 : 0;
    // if (isFailedAttempt)
    //   this.askForPasscode().subscribe();
    return !isFailedAttempt;
  }));
}

// this.askForPasscode().subscribe();
this.askForPasscode().pipe(
  map(result => result.data.values.passcode),
  switchMap(passcode => this.passcode.verifyPasscode(passcode)),
  map(isSuccessful => { if (!isSuccessful) throw 'error' }),
  retry({count: 5}),
).subscribe();
```

`verifyPasscode` now just verify the correctness of the passcode, and returns a flag.
`askForPasscode` now have a bunch of pipeable operators which (1) read the flag, (2) throw an error if the verification failed, and (3) resubscribe if an error was thrown.

However, the dialog is not presented again if the passcode is wrong.
It looks like the `askForPasscode()` is not invoked again no matter what.
What am I missing?

Comment: can you create this as stackblitz or other runnable example?

Comment: Sure, here is a StackBlitz. As you can see, the dialog is dismissed no matter what passcode you type. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-hefepo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your stackblitz-example to make it work as intended:

**[Stackblitz-Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-7ermqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**What were the issues with your code?**

- When `retry` is triggered, `fromPromise(this.alertCtrl.create(alertOpts))` is **not** executed, while the subsequent `switchMap` actually is. Therefore `alert.present()` refers to an alert that was already dismissed.
- Because you placed the `alertOpts` inside the function, its properties would not be updated on failed login-attempts and therefore the `${this.failedAttempts} failed attempts` message would not have been displayed ever.

**How did I resolve the issues?**

- In the `askForPasscode()` method, I wrapped all `alert` promises in a `defer` operator which creates a new observable each time it is subscribed to.
- I've moved the alert options out into a separate function so that they are reassembled from scratch each time a login fails, thus showing the correct number of failed login attempts.

```
failedAttempts = 0;

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.askForPasscode()
    .pipe(
      map((result: any) => result.data.values.passcode),
      switchMap((passcode) => this.verifyPasscode(passcode)),
      map((isSuccessful) => {
        if (!isSuccessful) throw 'error';
      }),
      retry({ count: 5 })
    )
    .subscribe();
}

askForPasscode(): Observable<any> {
  return defer(async () => {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create(this.getLoginModal());
    await alert.present();
    return alert.onDidDismiss();
  });
}

verifyPasscode(passcode: string) {
  return of('passcode').pipe(
    map((stored) => {
      const isFailedAttempt = passcode !== stored;
      this.failedAttempts = isFailedAttempt ? this.failedAttempts + 1 : 0;
      return !isFailedAttempt;
    })
  );
}

getLoginModal() {
  return {
    backdropDismiss: false,
    header: 'passcodeEnter',
    message: this.failedAttempts
      ? `${this.failedAttempts} failed attempts`
      : '',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'passcode',
        placeholder: 'enter passcode',
        attributes: { type: 'password' },
      },
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'confirm',
      },
    ],
  };
}
```